# Loss doesn't decrease in training the pytorch RNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

Here is the RNN network I designed for a sentiment.

```
class rnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.h2o = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.h2h = nn.Linear(hidden_size , hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.Tanh()
        self.sigmoid = nn.LogSigmoid()

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        hidden_new = self.relu(self.i2h(input)+self.h2h(hidden))
        output = self.h2o(hidden)
        output = self.sigmoid(output)
        return output, hidden_new

    def init_hidden(self):
        return Variable(torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size))
```

Then, I create and train the network as :

```
RNN = rnn(50, 50, 1)
learning_rate = 0.0005
criteria = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(RNN.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
hidden = RNN.init_hidden()
epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i in range(len(train['Phrase'])):
        input = convert_to_vectors(train['Phrase'][i])
        for j in range(len(input)):
            temp_input = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(input[j]))
            output, hidden = RNN(temp_input, hidden)
        temp_output = torch.FloatTensor([np.float64(train['Sentiment'][i])/4])
        loss = criteria( output, Variable(temp_output))
        loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
        if (i%20 == 0):
            print('Current loss is ', loss)
```

The problem is that the loss of the network isn't decreasing. It increases, then decreases and so on. It isn't stable at all. I tried using a smaller learning rate but it doesn't seem to help.

Why is this happening and how can I rectify this?

Comment: May I ask why you don't simply use torch.nn.RNN ?

Comment: @ZEWEICHU I wanted to implement the RNN form scratch. Any reason behind this error?

Comment: You have `LogSigmoid` and `MSELoss`, is it correct? Can you share more about your dataset? Provide a training example, so that we can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `optimizer.step()` after you do `loss.backward()`.

Which, by the way, illustrates a common misconception: **Backpropagation is not a learning algorithm**, it's just a cool way of computing the gradient of the loss w.r.t. your parameters. You then use some variant of Gradient Descent (eg. plain SGD, AdaGrad, etc., in your case Adam) to update the weights given the gradients.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things which I think may give you some help.
First, in rnn class module, you'd better use `"super(rnn,self).__init__()"` to replace `"super().__init__()"`.

Second, the variable name should be consistent with the function, you'd better to use `"self.tanh = nn.Tanh()"` to replace `"self.relu = nn.Tanh()"`. And in rnn, the sigmoid function should be `1/(1+exp(-x))`, instead of the logsigmoid function. You should use `"self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()"` to replace `"self.sigmoid = nn.LogSigmoid()"`.
Third, the output should be activated by the softmax fucntion, if you use the rnn to classify. So you should add two statements,`"self.softmax = nn.Softmax()"` and `"output = self.softmax(output)"`.

Comment: Why would you prefer `super(rnn,self).__init__()` over `super().__init__()` ?

Comment: Because I am used to python2. And super().__init__() is also ok in python3.